# How does a fusible wire deployment mechanism work?

Tags: simulation, electronics, payload-deployment, mechanisms, education

#### Situation

Me and my student team are considering to use fusible wires in our [CanSat](https://www.esa.int/Education/CanSat/What_is_a_CanSat) to control the parachute and payload deployment.

In detail, a mechanism using a fusible wire should release a loaded spring which will then provide the necessary force to operate both of our deployment mechanisms.

#### Questions

##### 1:

What do we have to be aware of, when we want to use this type of mechanism in our CanSat, where space is a very valuable resource and how could such a mechanism work?

Is "direct holding" of the spring (0.75kg-1kg of force) by the wire itself an option? Or does it need a type of release mechanism which is triggered by a fusible wire?

##### 2:

What material (and in which diameter) can a fusible wire be made of, to have the lowest melting point possible...
[...and how much power would that draw approx. using a 7.6V PCDU]

Comment: Not an answer, but a common cubsat design choice is to use fishing line, and melt it with a small heater. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331467215_Design_Analysis_and_Testing_of_Monopole_Antenna_Deployment_Mechanism_for_BIRDS-2_CubeSat_Applications . One reason for doing this is that with the right line choices deployment can also occur after heater failure just by waiting for UV degradation of the line.